# Could Django be getting wrong content_type_id for a model?

Tags: mysql, django

When I edit an object (user 276) in django-admin, I get a foreign key error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/276/change/

(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`my_db_name`.`django_admin_log`, CONSTRAINT 
`django_admin__content_type_id_c4bce8eb_fk_django_content_type_id` 
FOREIGN KEY (`content_type_id`) REFERENCES `django_content_type` (`id`))')
```

On checking the records against user 276 in the django_admin_log table, I see that the field content_type_id is 126.

`mysql> select id, object_id, content_type_id, user_id from django_admin_log order by id;
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| id | object_id | content_type_id | user_id |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|  1 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
|  6 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
|  8 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
|  9 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
| 10 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
| 11 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
| 13 | 1         |             144 |     276 |
| 16 | 1         |             182 |     276 |
| 19 | 276       |             126 |     276 |
+----+-----------+-----------------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

When I look at the django_content_types table, I see id 126 is indeed there and relates to the correct type:

`mysql> select * from django_content_type order by id;
+-----+---------------+---------------------------------+
| id  | app_label     | model                           |
+-----+---------------+---------------------------------+
| 124 | auth          | group                           |
| 125 | auth          | permission                      |
| 126 | auth          | user                            |
| 127 | contenttypes  | contenttype                     |
| 128 | sessions      | session                         |
| 129 | sites         | site                            |
| 130 | admin         | logentry                        |
| 131 | account       | emailconfirmation               |`

So everything seems correct there for older logs, but now, for some reason, when editing a user in admin, Django is attempting to insert a row into django_admin_log for user 276 with a content_id that is something other than 126 (else we would not be getting the FK constraint).

The question is: how could django be getting an incorrect content_type_id for a model? Or is something else happening?

Additional info:

1. I don't think I'm doing anything funny in admin.py files but please ask if you want to see any.
2. I am doing very funny stuff with the MySQL connection as its a multi-tenant architecture site using [django-db-multitenant](https://github.com/mik3y/django-db-multitenant)

Using django 2.0 with MySQL on Ubuntu.

Comment: No, since you *edit* the record, you most likely *change* the value to a non-sensical id. So the commit is not *processed*, the database rejects it.

Comment: Makes sense. I have updated the question to reflect this.